# Error during update

Tags: updates

When I try to Update my 14.04 ubuntu It sort

```
A problem occurred during the update. 
This is usually some sort of network problem, 
please check your network connection and retry.
```

```
W:Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 193.206.139.34 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 193.206.139.34 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 193.206.139.34 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 193.206.139.34 80]
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've installed it years ago with a 11.04 disk and I think it has some problems with EOL updates... anyone knows how to fix it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must first delete old apt *lists* files from this path:

```
/var/lib/apt/lists/
```

then update apt:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Or just check that your local mirror is online. Try to switch to main server temporarily.

Comment: How can I do that? I mean, how can I search for the old ones?

Comment: mirrors are in this file: `/etc/apt/sources.list`.this [link](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) can help you to regenerate your _source.lists_ file.