# Trouble upgrading from 16.04 (network problem?)

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

This is the current version I have

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

When I try

```
sudo do-release-upgrade


Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

If I try

```
ThinkPad-T520:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for usernameXYZ: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

-ThinkPad-T520:~$ lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
    Release:    16.04
    Codename:   xenial

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error during update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685439/error-during-update)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a network problem but perhaps a procedural one.

To upgrade from the command line you need to follow these steps:

Open up a terminal window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd>

Issue the command `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Enter your user password

Look over the list of available updates and decide if you want to go through with the entire upgrade

To accept all updates click the <kbd>y</kbd> key and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Other than that there is a new procedure too... acknowledgements to itsfoss

[image]

Comment: That didn't work either. I entered the results in the original post above, rather than a comment, so they can be better formatted. But basically I was not offered any potential upgrades, it just didn't find anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps wait for the point release of 18.04.1 due shortly?

Comment: No problem, will do. Any idea when it should be released, and what command I should run to get it? Please add it to your answer above.

Comment: @BaronYugovich I've edited my answer with an alternative approach. The point release is due soon.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need to update your 16.04 to the latest state first before doing the upgrade to 18.04, try.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Yes, did all this, same result. Any other idea?

Comment: Since you can perform the steps about error, your network is fine thus far. Let's try this. Start Software & Updates, on the second tab, uncheck everything and exit. Then retry the 3 commands again.

Comment: By second tab, you mean Other Software, uncheck everything there?

Comment: Tried it, same result.

Comment: could you post "ip route" (or "ip -6 route" if you are using ipv6), just want to make sure there isn't anything funny there. While you are at this, post "dig ca.archive.ubuntu.com". Also, when you did the "apt-get update" check that it is using using "c.archive.ubuntu.com"

Comment: I actually managed to upgrade to 17.10, thanks. Do you know how I can get the classical gnome look rather than unity? When I try to select it when logging in, I get a brief black screen, and then it sends me back to the login page.